# Orchard CulturePicker and CurrentCulturePicker

Tags: orchardcms, cultureinfo, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.8

I'm using orchard 1.8.1 and Culture picker.

After removing the culture filter in module (Orchard has it on core by default and so it has to be removed to avoid conflicts) I made it working when I'm logged on.

However anonymous user cannot change language (or better it seems that the cookie is set correclty but the filter does not works or does not picks the language)

I digged for permission and read all code but it seems nothing wrong.

Any idea why culture picker works only when I'm logged as admin and does not works when I browse anonymous?

It is probably something with 1.8 upgrade

This is a site that works (1.6):

http://social-media-marketing-day.web-marketing-manager.it/cina-russia-corea-asia-corso-digital-strategia-comunicazione

This is the one that does not works (1.8):

http://radici-group.linked-in.it/nylon-uso-vantaggi

Thanks

Comment: After a bit of investigation it seems that the problem is that the page is not properly refresed after culture change. And hard refresh of the page gets the new language. This is a great optimization if the page is the same but indeed after changing culture it is a different page so it should not be cached. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.

Since it is a caching problem I have added a fake lang parameter matching requested language to the requested url.
This should not harm existing urls but adds something different to url itself so that it is cached separately...

Any idea on how do it properly without change the url?